# Replacing first part of string by another

Tags: c#, regex

I need to replace multiple file names in a folder. Here is one of the files:

`Abc.CDE.EFG`

I need to replace the first part of the string before the dot ("ABC") and replace it with: "zef".

Any ideas? I found this but it takes out the dot and not sure how to add the "zef".

```
var input = _FileInfo.ToString(); 
var output = input.Substring(input.IndexOf(".").Trim())
```

Comment: Where is the `zef` in your example?

Comment: ZEF.cde.efg, need to replace the abc

Answer (score 3):

Since the question is tagged with regex, you can use a regular expression like so:

```
var input = "abc.def.efg";
var pattern = "^[^\\.]+";
var replacement = "zef";
var rgx = new Regex(pattern);
var output = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, try:

```
string myString = "Abc.CDE.EFG";    

//This splits your string into an array with 3 items
//"Abc", "CDE" and "EFG"    
var stringArray = myString.Split('.');  

//Now modify the first item by changing it to "zef" 
stringArray[0] = "zef"; 

//Then we rebuild the string by joining the array together
//delimiting each group by a period
string newString = string.Join(".", stringArray);
```

With this solution you can independently access any of the "blocks" just by referencing the array by index.

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VGaPih)

Comment: How can I use this with FileInfo? I need to add them to a directory afterwards

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  The result of `string.Join` (`newString`) is a string.  If you want to use it for other parts of your code just pass the string along.

Comment: For all the strings, I want to add them to a directory, got any ideas? It's in a foreach. So I pass through every FileInfo in a directory, I change their names and send them to another

Comment: What do you mean by directory?  You want to create folders on the file system that have the name of `newString`?

Comment: no, the newString is the new name of the file. I'm trying to modify the old filename's to newString and sending newString's to another directory, so like from c:\dev\1 to c:\dev\2.

Comment: Ah.  Well that's a bit outside of your original question.  You'll want to edit your question with more details (or preferably ask another question with tags specific to _that_ problem).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var input = _FileInfo.ToString(); 
    var output = "zef" + input.Substring(input.IndexOf("."));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the length of the first string , you can replace mentioning number of characters starting from position until the length you want to replace else.

```
string s = "Abc.CDE.EFG";
                string [] n = s.Split('.');
                n[0] = "ZEF";
                string p = string.Join(".",n);
                Console.WriteLine(p);
            }
```

Comment: @maccettura, So similar !